# How can I align component to be center in whole page?

Tags: html, css, center, vertical-alignment

I'm making [this site](https://pixelicons.com/) and working on second page. However, I have trouble for centering component in the whole viewport. I searched lots of solutions including `position`, `display:table`, etc. But, I couldn't know how to use for this situation.

```css
.header {
    background-color: #F7F7F7;
    padding: 15px;
}

.header h1 {
    float: left;
}

.header h1 img {
    display: block;
}

.header__nav {
    float: right;
}

.header__nav li {
    float: left;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 38px;
}

.header__nav li a {
    margin-right: 39px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.header__nav li a::after {
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: black;
    transition: 0.3s;
    display: block;
}

.header__nav li a:hover::after {
    width: 100%;
}

.header__nav li button:hover::before {
    width: 100%;
}

.contents {
    padding: 150px 100px;
}

.contents__inside {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

.contents__inside strong {
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

.contents__inside h2 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 6rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1;
}

.contents__inside img {
    width: 100%;
}

.contents__inside p {
    max-width: 860px;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.info__inside {
    font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

.info__inside h2 {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1;
}

.info__inside p {
    max-width: 860px;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    margin: 0 auto 100px;
}

.info__inside img {
    width: 100%;
}

.footer {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<header class="header clearfix">
    <div class="l-wrapper">
        <h1><a href="#"><img src="https://pixelicons.com/wp-content/themes/pexelicons/assets/pic/site-logo/logo.png" alt="Logo"></a></h1>
        <nav class="header__nav">
            <ul class="clearfix">
                <li><a href="#">View icons</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Buy now</a></li>
                <li><button class="menu">menu</button></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
<section class="contents">
    <div class="l-main">
        <div class="contents__inside">
            <strong>Top quality</strong>
            <h2>ICONS</h2>
            <p>6,500 unique icons in different categories. 
                Drawn by hand and designed for perfection.</p>
            <img src="https://pixelicons.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Home_slide_space.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="info">
    <div class="l-main">
        <div class="info__inside">
            <h2>Thousands of icons</h2>
            <p>6,500 unique icons in 3 style color, line and solid.</p>
            <img src="https://pixelicons.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Preview_rd_2.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<footer class="footer">
</footer>
```

Is there an any proper method to solve this issue? How can I implement like original design of website?

EDIT

> I don't wanna solve by using CSS3 property to practice CSS2

[IMAGE that I wanna fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vUZW.png)

Comment: unclear mate...

Comment: @dgknca What is unclear? Speak specifically

Comment: @Martijn That's for the horizontal alignment, but it cannot cover vertical alignment

Comment: You want the icons to be full screen? Or just take up half screen like the image you highlighted in red?

Comment: @Gosi Nope, I wanna make it same with original website. Just visit site and compare with my image. To be same, my image has to occupy full screen and align center.

Comment: But your snippet is occupying center and taking full screen (the icons)

Comment: Oh the 6500, that part?!

Comment: Yep. Exactly what I want

Comment: To be honest, your code seems correct. Just that, the image you use has alot of white space. Can you trim out the transparent space on the .png image and see. Your 100% width should work.

Comment: From which page you have to vertically center.. Can you please clearly ask your doubs or mention the page name as you want..

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you, You want to center your items in your div

To do that you can

```css
.yourDivClassName{
   display: flex; 
   flex-direction: column; 
   flex-wrap: wrap; 
   align-items:center; 
   justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
   <div class="yourDivClassName">
       <button>example button</button> 
       <p>example text</p>
       <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRFU7U2h0umyF0P6E_yhTX45sGgPEQAbGaJ4g&usqp=CAU" alt="example image">     
   </div>    
</body>
```